# GmailSettingsService availability post April 20th, 2015

Tags: java, gdata, google-admin-sdk

Will the GmailSettingsService class still be available after April 20th, and will the constructor still be as shown below (from https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/appsforyourdomain/gmailsettings/GmailSettingsService.java?r=505)

```
public GmailSettingsService(
  String applicationName, String domain, String username, String password)
  throws AuthenticationException {
    super(applicationName, Constants.PROTOCOL, Constants.APPS_APIS_DOMAIN);
    this.domain = domain;

    new GenericFeed().declareExtensions(getExtensionProfile());

    this.setUserCredentials(username + "@" + domain, password);
}
```

Is there any way to test my application before the April 20th expiration date for deprecated APIs to make sure it will work?

Comment: Here is the documentation on the Email Settings API, it is not mentioned that it is going to be deprecated: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Email Settings API is not part of the April 20th shutdown, [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps), which your code above is using for authentication is. You should migrate your code to use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).

Comment: Thanks Jay.  Is there any official documentation for the migration process?  I've been hunting around but have not found any.

Comment: Also, the Java documentation on https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#creating_a_send-as_alias includes the above login process with no indication that it's being expired.